# Charset issue in Control Panel

Tags: craft3, install

I'm trying to install Craft v3 on a web server currently running Craft 2. As far as I am aware all the required PHP extensions (including iconv) are installed; PHP v7.1.x

The front end works OK, but as soon as I go to the control panel I get this (devmode=true)

```
> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException iconv(): Wrong charset,
> conversion from `UTF-8' to `UTF-16BE' is not allowed
```

I should note that my method of installation involves getting the site working on a local machine and then copying everything over, and editing the .ENV and general.php accordingly. There is no added content or plugins installed - just an empty Craft install (latest version).

As far as I can see the database charset is set up correctly (UTF8).

What else should I be looking at?

UPDATE: digging around further, if I run a PHP test file,  this line

```
> $res=iconv('utf-8', 'UTF-16BE', 'test1');
```

throws the same error message. So I am guessing it is a server problem.

Comment: Just a guess, but your web server is configured to use UTF-16BE, but the version of iconv you have installed doesn't support it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question now that I have had the issue resolved. Clearly this is a local server environmental issue. The explanation I have received from the hosting provider is not one I understand too well, but here it is for the record.

> For security reasons, the PHP FPM process on your server executes
>   scripts in a separate chroot(2) environment, meaning that only a
>   limited set of resources are available at runtime.  This sometimes
>   causes problems when the chrooted program requires resources that
>   don't exist outside the chroot environment that are loaded during
>   runtime rather than being built in to the binary, or dynamically
>   linked before the system chroot call.  The iconv extension has this
>   problem, in loading .so binary data files corresponding to the
>   encodings it's manipulating.  On your server, the files it loads were
>   in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv, and had not been copied into the
>   chroot environment at /srv/php-fpm/rdc.  Copying the contents of
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv to
>   /srv/php-fpm/rdc/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv has fixed the issue.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest. ;)

Comment: Thanks @brad-bell. I knew you had it in hand!